# Euler number zero for odd dimensional compact manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-forms, smooth-manifolds

I need to prove that
every compact manifold of odd dimension has Euler number zero.

The Euler number of $M$ compact and oriented is
$$
e(M):=\int_Ms_0^*\phi(TM)
$$ 
where $s_0$ is the zero section of $TM$ and $\phi(TM)$ is its Thom class.
We also proved that
$$
e(M)=\sum_q (-1)^qh_{DR}^q(M)
$$
where $h_{DR}^q(M):=dim H_{DR}^q(M)$ and $H_{DR}^q(M)$ is the $q-th$ cohomology ring of $M$.

Comment: You might try to use the Poincare duality.

Comment: Shall I use the second formula for $e(M)$? @JohnMa

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @JohnMa to apply it I also need to strengthen the hypothesis and add $\partial M=\emptyset$, right?

Comment: Yes, I am always thinking of manifold without boundary. It seems that the statement is not true for manifold with boundary.

Comment: @JohnMa Could you check my proof? I'll post in two minutes

Comment: You can post it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose $M$ orientable. And let $dim(M)=2n+1$.

By Poincaré duality, we get 
$$
H^q(M)\cong (H^{2n+1-q}(M))^*
$$
for every $q$.

Since every compact manifold is of finite type (hence its cohomology rings are finite dimensional) and since every finite dimensional space is isomorphic to its dual, we get
$$
h^q(M)=h^{2n+1-q}(M)
$$
for every $q$.

Let's apply the formula
$$
e(M)=\sum_q(-1)^qh^q(M)
$$
We see that all the terms $h^q(M)$ and $h^{2n+1-q}(M)$ delete.

Comment: It's very clear and correct.

Comment: Thank you  @JohnMa! I thought it would have been harder

Comment: But what about the non-orientable case?

Comment: I am not sure, you need to make sense of the integral first.

Comment: My professor defined $e(M)$ just for orientable manifolds

Comment: It seems that even for the general definition it is only defined on oriented vector bundle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_class

Comment: Okay so, probably the exercise is missing one hypothesis

Comment: @avati91 I  was wrong about my last comment...there was a calculation mistake, actually any closed manifold of odd dimensional manifold has eular characteristic is zero, for a non-orientable manifold, if you consider homology with $\mathbb{Z_2}$ coefficient then orientibility makes sense, and there you can repeat the same argument, only need to check that this alternative sum is actually same as alternative sum with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficient...

Comment: Okay, but I haven't studied homology theory